# Count duplicate values via Elasticsearch terms aggregation

Tags: search, elasticsearch, aggregation

I am trying to run an Elasticsearch terms aggregation on multiple fields of the documents in my index. Each document contains multiple fields with hashtags, which can be extracted using a custom hashtag analyzer. The goal is to find the most common hashtags in the system.

As stated in the [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation), it is not possible to run a terms aggregation on multiple fields of a document. I am thus trying to use a `copy_to` field. The problem now is, that if the document contains the same hashtag in multiple fields, it should count the term multiple times. This is not the case with the default terms aggregation:

**Given Mapping:**

```
{
  "properties": {
  "field_one": {
    "type": "string",
    "copy_to": "hashtags"
  },
  "field_two": {
    "type": "string",
    "copy_to": "hashtags"
  }
}
```

**Given Document:**

```
{
  "field_one": "Hello #World",
  "field_two": "One #World",
}
```

The aggregation will return a single bucket `{"key": "#World", "doc_count": 1}`. What I need is a single bucket `{"key": "#World", "doc_count": 2}`.

Comment: It works as expected. There is only one document that has the `key` `#World`, not two. The fact that two fields have the same terms is something different.

Comment: I know that this works as expected. However, I am looking for a way to achieve the second solution...

Comment: One idea is a script field: `"script_fields": {
    "test1": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "groovy",
        "inline": "_index['hashtags']['#World'].tf()"
      }
    }
  }` and enable groovy scripting in yml config file with `script.engine.groovy.inline.search: true`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would have to hard code the hashtag in the script field of the query. However, I don't know the terms berforehand...

Comment: Did you try nested documents? i haven't done any aggregations on nested documents, but you could look there. Just a guess.